# Urllib and BeautifulSoup flexible urlopen() options

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urlopen

You were all tremendously helpful with my last question, and so I though I would pose a new question about an issue I have been facing. I imported BeautifulSoup, and am trying to export data from the database of med schools on this site: https://services.aamc.org/msar/home. I created a "for" loop to open and parse the website, and then print data from the specific span that contains the city and state of the school. After executing the code, I was excited to find that my code was working!!..and dismayed to see it return an error after the third school. Upon snooping around for a possible problem, I saw that some of the schools I was pulling data from use the url "https://services.aamc.org/msar/**program**Details/(code)/about", instead of https://services.aamc.org/msar/**schoolDetails**/(code)/about (which I had set as my url in the code), and therefore my program is trying to pull span data from a webpage that does not exist!

Does anyone know of a way to define a url in my "url = " that says "identify this url OR that url", or maybe an option to skip over that part of the url and simply match the code and /about part of the url? What is most important is that the code return the city information in the SAME order that it appears on the database, since I will be importing all this data into columns in CSV format and lining them up. So it can't be in random order.

Thanks, and I really appreciate the help.

Matt (sorry part of the code below does not appear in the code window!)

---

```
import requests
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://services.aamc.org/msar/home#null"
search_url = "https://services.aamc.org/msar/search/resultData"

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(url)  # visit main page

    # search
    data = {
        "start": "0",
        "limit": "500",
        "sort": "",
        "dir": "",
        "newSearch": "true",
        "msarYear": ""
    }
    response = session.post(search_url, data=data)
    import csv
    # extract search results
    results = response.json()["searchResults"]["rows"]

    codes = []

    for result in results:
        codes.append(int(result["key"]))


for code in codes:
    url = "https://services.aamc.org/msar/schoolDetails/%d/about" % code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

    city = soup.find("span", {"style": "font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;"})

    for span in city:
        print(span)
```

Comment: Does `["searchResults"]["rows"]` contains information about the correct URL?

Comment: Yes, so if you look at the "search_url", you will see the code for all the info on the main page "https://services.aamc.org/msar/home". I am trying to go into the pages for each school (https://services.aamc.org/msar/schoolDetails/%d/about" % code) and scrape the city. Problem is, sometimes the site for the individual school is "https://services.aamc.org/msar/schoolDetails/%d/about" % code", and sometimes it is "https://services.aamc.org/msar/programDetails/%d/about" % code". I dont know a command in BeautifulSoup to allow for a string in a url to be *either "schoolDetails" OR "programDetails

Comment: I'm thinking an "if/else statement might work", but I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't see any information regarding the correct URL for each school at the "search_url" page, is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: So you are right. What I am telling it to do is to navigate to the site of each school in the list on the main page https://services.aamc.org/msar/home. If you click on one (e.g. Albany medical school) and then the next one (Albert Einstein), you'll see that the URLs are identical except for the code "https:...Details/[code]/about". I got those codes from the search_url, and tried to make a for loop to insert this code into a basic https template "https://services.aamc.org/msar/schoolDetails/[code]/about". Problem is, some schools not have "schoolDetails" before the code, but "programDetails".

Comment: I was about to suggest to store information about the URL if it exists at the "search_url" (something along this line `result["url"]`), but turned out it doesn't exist, so please see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that information regarding the correct URL for each school is not available beforehand, you can use `try ... except...` construct to try the first URL format, and then try the second URL format only if the first returned 'page not found' (put the less likely URL, if any, in `url2` to minimize miss-hit case) :

```py
from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError
.....

url1 = "https://services.aamc.org/msar/schoolDetails/%d/about"
url2 = "https://services.aamc.org/msar/programDetails/%d/about"
for code in codes:
    soup = None

    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url1 % code))
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.getcode() == 404: # page not found
            print("first URL not found, trying the second URL...")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url2 % code))

    city = soup.find("span", {"style": "font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;"})
```

Comment: This works, but cannot pull data from all the sites that have "programDetails" in the link. I think this is because the error that pops up for these websites is. This seems to be because it is still unable to execute the try/except function, and therefore the site is not readable. The error code is "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". It leaves these values as none.